# Adobe after effects edit templates

Tags: after-effects, adobe

im struggling to edit the template of an intro. Im quite new to adobe after effects, ideally i want to change the logo and text. Ive managed to change the text underneath the logo but no the logo itself. I tried to remove the logo, but it says "Are you sure, this logo is used in 10 other compositions"

Any suggestions?

https://motionarray.com/after-effects-templates/glitch-logo-476737/

[image]